# Books friendly to self-studying Industrial Organization

Tags: self-study, industrial-organisation

I'm currently an undergraduate freshman looking for resources to self-read Industrial Organization. I've read Varian's undergraduate book cover-to-cover and have a decent understanding of basic game theory, and I own the book 
[Industrial Organization: Theory and Applications by Pepall-Richards-Norman](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B00I8XF6XW)

Is there another book that would be better for someone who wants a rigorous treatment of IO that is mathematically advanced but theoretically digestable, or is this one optimal? (By the time I begin to self-read, I'll have finished most of baby Rudin).

Answer (score 8):

While taking Industrial Organization I remember working with:

1. *Strategies and games: theory and practice* by Dutta
2. *Introduction to industrial organization* by Cabral
3. *Industrial organization: theory and applications* by Shy
4. *Industrial Organization: Markets and Strategies* by Belleflamme and Peitz

The first two are rather introductory while third and forth are more advanced (getting into greater detail with a little bit more advanced maths). You can probably find them online if you try.

And on top of that, I really enjoyed *The Economics of industrial organization* by Shepherd. It is way older than the others but still made quite a good read.

Comment: I don’t know the first three but bellflame’s book is good I would recommend it as well

Comment: I recommend it as well, but there are two authors, Paul Belleflamme and Martin Peitz. Let me edit that in.

Answer (score 3):

I would recommend the The theory of Industrial Organization and the Game Theory from Jean Tirole

Comment: It is a great book, but perhaps a little outdated.

Answer (score 1):

For a slightly different perspective and somewhat newer tools, I would suggest "Oligopoly Pricing: Old Ideas and New Tools" by Xavier Vives.